# Add a custom button to Customer registration form on the admin

Tags: magento2, customer, custom-button

I want to add a custom button like "Generate a random email", into customer registration form section.

"Generate a random email" button will send an email to customer which are created from the admin (Customers-> All Customers-> Add New Customer).

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code in your custom module.

**`Setp1:-`** Override **`customer_listing.xml`** file in your custom module.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <settings>
        <buttons>
            <button name="CustomerEmailGenerate" class="YourVendorName\YourModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\Customer\CustomerEmailGenerate"/>
        </buttons>
    </settings>
</listing>
```

**`Setp2:-`** Create defined class in your module like **YourVendorName\YourModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\Customer\CustomerEmailGenerate.php**

```
<?php
namespace YourVendorName\YourModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\Customer;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Control\ButtonProviderInterface;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context;

class CustomerEmailGenerate implements ButtonProviderInterface
{

    /**
     * @var Context
     */
    private $context;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context
    ) {
        $this->context = $context;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve button-specified settings
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getButtonData()
    {

        return [
            'label' => __('Customer Email Generate'),
            'on_click' => sprintf("location.href = '%s';", $this->getGenerateEmail()),
            'class' => 'primary',
            'sort_order' => 20
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get Generate Email URL
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getGenerateEmail()
    {
        return $this->context->getUrlBuilder()->getUrl('frontendname/controllername/actionname', []);
    }
}
```

Some decription for understanding:-

You can have additional buttons. As many as you want.
Each class declared inside the 'item' tag must implement the interface **`Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Control\ButtonProviderInterface`**.
in the method **`getButtonData`** you define how the button looks or behaves.

**See Below Screenshot**

[image]

**`THANKS.`**

Comment: Thanks for the help but I need the button in the actual form updated question with a new screen shot. Again Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to
**app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/customer_listing.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <settings>
        <buttons>
            <button name="CustomButton" class="Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Customer\CustomButton"/>
        </buttons>
    </settings>
</listing>
```

In **app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Customer/CustomButton.php** file add the following code:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Customer;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Control\ButtonProviderInterface;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context;

class CustomButton implements ButtonProviderInterface
{

    private $context;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context
    ) {
        $this->context = $context;
    }

    public function getButtonData()
    {

        return [
            'label' => __('Custom Button'),
            'on_click' => sprintf("location.href = '%s';", $this->getBackUrl()),
            'class' => 'primary',
            'sort_order' => 10
        ];
    }

    public function getBackUrl()
    {
        return $this->context->getUrlBuilder()->getUrl('your/controller/url', []);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey @vivek ghetia Vivek thanks for the help! but I did write the question properly. I actually want the custom button the the form. added a new image to the question